# php crop part of image and save it as thumball on given path. without any external jquery library

Tags: php, image, crop

i have many large size images i want to only crop only middle part of these  images size (100x100) with original  resolution and save it as thumball on given path. here is my

```
<?php
$img = "../QcImages/file.jpg";

square_crop($img,'old.jpg');


 function square_crop($src_image, $dest_image, $thumb_size = 100, $jpg_quality = 90) {

// Get dimensions of existing image
$image = getimagesize($src_image);

// Check for valid dimensions
if( $image[0] <= 0 || $image[1] <= 0 ) return false;

// Determine format from MIME-Type
$image['format'] = strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*?\//', '', $image['mime']));

// Import image
switch( $image['format'] ) {
    case 'jpg':
    case 'jpeg':
        $image_data = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_image);
    break;
    case 'png':
        $image_data = imagecreatefrompng($src_image);
    break;
    case 'gif':
        $image_data = imagecreatefromgif($src_image);
    break;
    default:
        // Unsupported format
        return false;
    break;
}

// Verify import
if( $image_data == false ) return false;

// Calculate measurements
if( $image[0] & $image[1] ) {
    // For landscape images
    $x_offset = ($image[0] - $image[1]) / 2;
    $y_offset = 0;
    $square_size = $image[0] - ($x_offset * 2);
} else {
    // For portrait and square images
    $x_offset = 400;
    $y_offset = ($image[1] - $image[0]) / 2;
    $square_size = $image[1] - ($y_offset * 2);
}

// Resize and crop
$img = imagecreatetruecolor('100','100'); // I created a new canvas 
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_size, $thumb_size);
imagecopy($img,$image_data, 0, 0, 120, 120, 200, 150); //  Edited new code 
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_size, $thumb_size);
if( imagecopyresampled(
    $canvas,
    $image_data, /// i know this is actual image which is copied in new thumball image but i have no idea how to crop only little part of it rather than using whole image.
    0,
    0,
    $x_offset, // i tried editing this offset 
    $y_offset, // and this offset 
    $thumb_size,
    $thumb_size,
    $square_size,
    $square_size
)) {

    // Create thumbnail
    switch( strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*\./', '', $dest_image)) ) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            //return imagejpeg($canvas, $dest_image, $jpg_quality);//
           return imagejpeg($img,$dest_image,90);// New Edited 
        break;
        case 'png':
            return imagepng($canvas, $dest_image);
        break;
        case 'gif':
            return imagegif($canvas, $dest_image);
        break;
        default:
            // Unsupported format
            return false;
        break;
    }

     } else {
    return false;
     }
    }
    ?>
```

But this code resizing whole image and saving it as thumball... i don't want to resize whole image i only want to crop any part form image Size (100X100) and save it is as thumball sorry for bad english

Thank you asking me to edit code..  i tried this code again with some new editing and it is working fine thank you very much ...

Comment: Well then feed matching coordinates – which you calculate first, based on the dimensions of the original image – to `imagecopyresampled` …

Comment: i tried  but its not working.. can you please give example...

Comment: Show us (and _explain_) what you have tried (by editing your question).

Comment: thank you very much i was editing this code to show you where i was getting problem .. and tried to execute again .. and got expected result ... thank you  :)